# Why instance a new fragment inside a public static class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Reference: [Fragment Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

I am new to Java and Android and going through the online android guide. I have two questions:

**Question 1:** Why is there a need to create a new instance of DetailsFragment within the
public static class?

**Question 2:** The "Create a new instance" further declares a new DetailsFragment. Overall
there are four places where the same name "DetailsFragment" is used. This is very confusing.
Please explain?

---

```
public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    /* Create a new instance of DetailsFragment, initialized
       to show the text at 'index'. */

    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

        // Supply index input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's called the [`static factory method` pattern](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=21), and in this case allows you to easily create a new instance of the fragment with all of the required arguments populated, without having to know about the internal implementation. For example, without this, to create a properly initialized instance of the Fragment, you would use:

```
DetailsFragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("index", index);
fragment.setArguments(args);
// Then use the fragment however you need it
```

Using the static factory method, all of that logic is internalized into the Fragment itself, and you can simply use:

```
DetailsFragment fragment = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);
// Then use the fragment
```

Answer (score 2):

The best practice for Fragments is to use a static `newInstance()` method because the Android system needs (and will use) an empty public constructor to create your Fragment in many cases.

For example, if you display a `DetailsFragment` and the user then locks their device and comes back half an hour later, Android will attempt to recreate the state of your application, and when it needs to re-instantiate the `DetailsFragment`, it will use an empty public constructor.

Fragments do, however, support arguments using `setArguments(Bundle)`. Thus you can use a static `newInstance()` method in place of a constructor to set arguments that are required to re-create the Fragment.

In the example of this `DetailsFragment`, when Android re-creates the Fragment the `index` variable will  still be available to the Fragment by calling `getArguments().getInt("index")`. If you had created the `index` variable in a constructor, that information would be lost when the Fragment is re-created.